# await/async: compiler/syntax issue with conditionnals

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I am using async/await in a web app to query a DB and use results for other queries.

I have this function:

```
exports.getByUserAndPurposeForService = async (req,res,next) =>{

    var serviceID =  await Service.getIdByName(req.params.serviceName)
    var user_id =   await User.getIdByName(req.params.userID)

    if(condition){...}
```

Await/async works great there but whet it gets to this point:

```
else {

    var userName=  **await** ID.getUserID(serviceID, req.params.userID)
    user_id =  **await** User.getIdByName(userName)
    }
    else{
        res.send('Not Allowed')
    }
        }

    })
```

those two 'await' create an error in the IDE :

> 'Parsing error : unexpected token ID'

I don't know why, I can use await on functions outside the conditional but not inside.

Comment: `await ID.getUserID(serviceID, req.params.userID)`? Did you meant: `await Service.getUserID(serviceID, req.params.userID)`?

Comment: Maybe related : https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8366

Comment: @Silvermind no ID is a model i call as well, even if i change it to Service in else, i get the same error..

Comment: @Pac0 thanks but thats not it, i had that problem a few days back : just wrong version of node

Comment: Ok, so your issue is solved, is that correct ? in that case you can answer your own question by describing the version issues and how you fixed it, for future readers .

Comment: Without knowing the source of `ID` and `User`, the only error I see is that you did not declare `user_id`: `const user_id = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all the help, I found what the problem was :
I was awaiting these promises inside a .exec() function

Like this :

```
Model.findOne({..}).exec(function(err, result){
var user = await ...
})
```

You can't apparently mix chaining with async/await
Thanks for the help !

So I fixed it by using await on Model.findOne({..}).exec() and storing result in variable I could use after